# Spring - configuring a class not as a bean though

Tags: java, spring

I have a Spring-managed bean (Application-scoped, or a singleton in the Spring world) that has properties within it that are a list of objects.

I'd like to configure those objects in XML if that is possible without too much effort.

If I declare them as a bean, then I can inject them, but I don't want them to be Spring-managed beans, the configuration is longer, and there is additional overhead associated with making them beans (memory + cpu cycles).

In JBoss Seam, Jetty, I can instantiate components like so:

```
<New class="" id="">
  <Arg/>
  <Arg>
    <New class=""/>
  </Arg>
</New>
```

In JBoss Seam:

```
<mypackage:class-name id="someComponent">
  <component:property name="items">
     <mypackage:other-class-name title="The Great Gatsby" pages="201"/>
  </...>
</...>
```

I want the main item to be a component / bean, but not the inner components.  I just want those to be anonymous, no lifecycle associated with them other than the lifecycle inherited from their parent.

The inner items would be mypackage:other-class-name and the New within the Arg element.

Thanks,

Walter

Comment: Who do you expect to process the XML if not Spring?

Comment: Please give a short example of what you want to do

Comment: How many objects are there? To me it seems that there need to be at least a couple of thousands of those so that making them (inner) beans would really be any kind of an overhead that is noticeable by anybody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that it is possible. Maybe what you need are [**inner beans definitions**](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-inner-beans).

```
<bean id="outer" class="...">
<!-- instead of using a reference to a target bean, simply define the target bean inline -->
  <property name="target">
    <bean class="com.example.Person"> <!-- this is the inner bean -->
      <property name="name" value="Fiona Apple"/>
      <property name="age" value="25"/>
    </bean>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thats's the first thought I had. The only other thing I could think of is to used well known property values to instantiate the right objects in the bean. (i.e. <property name="fooDaoImpl" value="fooJdbcDao"/>)  Contrived example, but another possibility.

Comment: Ok, I guess that will suffice, not as streamlined, but it gets the job done I suppose.